# How to explode block with pyautocad

Tags: python

I am importing a .dwg file to another AutoCAD file using pyautocad.
It shows the object as a block and now I have to explode it and I don't know how.
If anyone can help me with how I explode the block will be greatly appreciated.

```
from pyautocad import Autocad,APoint
acad = Autocad(create_if_not_exists = True)
p1 = APoint(0,0)
blockp = acad.model.InsertBlock(p1,"C:\S20 A.dwg",1,1,1,0)

print (blockp.name)
```

Comment: Provide some code ?

Comment: I edited the post to include the code.

Comment: What does "explode" mean for you? Add some powder and ignite it and have some fancy effects? Explode into triangles or is the DWG already broken into pieces? Or do you actually want an exploded view drawing?

Comment: In VBA there is a command "Explode" that ungroups a block. I am asking how to ungroup a block in pyautocad.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to work around the 'KeyError:9'. I made an exception when using the command 'entity.Explode()' and after, loop through the blocks in ModelSpace to get the inserted block again. If somebody help me in how to correct the syntax to avoid this 'KeyError:9' will be appreciated.

```
import array
from comtypes import COMError
from comtypes.client import CreateObject,GetModule, GetActiveObject
try:
    acad = GetActiveObject("AutoCAD.Application")
    
except(OSError, COMError): 
    acad = CreateObject("AutoCAD.Application",dynamic=True)


filename = r"C:\Test\CP20 IMPERIAL.dwt" 
doc = acad.Documents.Open(filename) 

files = r"C:\Test\Series 20\S20 A.dwg" 
insertionPnt = array.array('d', [0,0,0])
blockI = doc.ModelSpace.InsertBlock(insertionPnt, files, 1, 1, 1, 0) 
acad.visible = True
if blockI: 
    try:
        eent = blockI.Explode()  
        print('Exploded')
    except KeyError:
        print("Explode with Error") 
try:
    ssBlocks = doc.SelectionSets.Add("AllBlockRefs")
except:
    ssBlocks = doc.SelectionSets.Item("AllBlockRefs")

SELECT_ALL = 5
FilterType = array.array('h',[0]) 
FilterData = ['Insert'] 

ssBlocks.Select(SELECT_ALL,(0,0,0),(0,0,0),FilterType,FilterData)

icount = ssBlocks.Count
print(icount)
for entity in ssBlocks:

name = entity.Name 
print(name)
if name == 'S20 A': 
    try:
        entity.Explode() 
        print('Exploded')
    except KeyError:
        print("Explode with Error") 
    
entity.Delete() 

ssBlocks.Clear
ssBlocks.Delete
for entity in doc.ModelSpace:
    name = entity.EntityName
    if name == "AcDbBlockReference":
        if entity.IsDynamicBlock:
            print(entity.Name)
            print("Is Dinamic Block")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).